# How to call a Source file in a Bash Script?

Tags: bash

I have a variables source file called my.vars located in ~/. In it I have:

```
FIRSTNAME=John
LASTNAME=Doe
FIRSTANDLASTNAME=John Doe
```

In a script I call the source file using:

```
. ~/my.vars
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
line 3: Doe: command not found
```

I read somewhere that the source command actually runs the program so it maybe seeing the space as a delimiter.

How can I call the variables source file in my script? I've tried also:

```
source ~/my.vars
```

Same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that as you have a space in variable value, as a result the first part is being assigned as the variable value and the last part is being treated as a standalone command, leading to the error.

So the variable is being set as `FIRSTANDLASTNAME=John` and `Doe` is being taken as a command.

You need either quoting or escaping, any one of the following would do:

```
FIRSTANDLASTNAME="John Doe"
FIRSTANDLASTNAME='John Doe'
FIRSTANDLASTNAME=John\ Doe
```

Now you would be able to `source` (`.`) the file expectedly.